# How to write custom NLog target that can lookup value from appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I want get host and token from appsettings.json in `nlog.config`. I have followed [this article](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer)  but  I can't get correct value in `appsettings.json`.

This is my custom NLog target:

[[image: My NLog Target Code]

This is my custom `NLog.config`:

[[image: My Nlog.config]

This is my custom `appsettings.json`:

[[image: My Appsettings.json]

Anyone help me check why I can't value, please.

Answer (score 0):

Never understood sharing code using screenshots, but anyway you need to change your properties from type `string` into `Layout` like this:

```
public Layout Host { get; set; }
```

Then you render the output like this:

```
protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
{
    var host = RenderLogEvent(this.Host, logEvent);

    // blah blah
}
```

Have updated the wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target